# Number of spanning trees

Tags: graph-theory

How many labelled spanning trees exist for the following graph?

[image]

I count 5 possible labelled spanning trees in total. Is anyone in agreement?

[[image]]

Comment: I suspect there are more.  Can you list your five?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I count 9.${}{}$

Comment: I've posted a picture of the ones I've got

Comment: Hint: You always need the edge $(2,5)$, and then you can configure both ends independently. The [multiplication principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) applies.

Answer (score 1):

For your question, we just calculate the value of  the tutte polynomial of your graph at $(1,1)$

In Mathematica it is easy to do that:

```
g = Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 5 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 
   5 \[UndirectedEdge] 1, 5 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 
   2 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 
   2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3}]
f[x_, y_] := TuttePolynomial[g, {x, y}]
```

```
f[x, y]
```

$x^5+2 x^4+2 x^3 y+x^3+2 x^2 y+x y^2$

```
f[1,1] 
(*f[1,1]=9*)
```

So the number of spanning trees of your graph is 9.

---

[The wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte_polynomial#Individual_points) shows:

what does 【the value of tutte polynomial at Individual points】  mean:

###### (1,1)

$T_G(1,1)$ counts the number of spanning forests (edge subsets without cycles and the same number of connected components as $G$ ).

If the graph is connected, $T_G(1,1)$ counts the number of spanning trees.

###### (2,1)

$T_{G}(2,1)$ counts the number of forests, i.e., the number of acyclic edge subsets.

##### (1,2)

$T_{G}(1,2)$ counts the number of spanning subgraphs (edge subsets with the same number of connected components as $G$).

##### (2,2)

$T_G(2,2)$ is the number $ 2^{|E|}$ where  $|E|$ is the number of edges of graph $G$.

###### (2,0)

$T_{G}(2,0)$ counts the number of acyclic orientations of $G$.

###### (0,2)

$T_{G}(0,2)$ counts the number of strongly connected orientations of G.